# Can you use variables when setting up restrictions on addresses that ssh server listens on?

Tags: 12.04, server

I am setting up some virtual ubuntu 12.04 servers and was wondering if you could use a variable or a string that represented the ip or interface? I was trying to make a template that could be used to spin up new copies of the original and wasnt sure if ubuntu supported that, such as eth0 or eth1 instead of 10.X.X.X

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom image

You can [build a custom image/cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) for installation of Ubuntu.

It's not an overly simple process.

### simple-cdd

You could also try [simple-cdd](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/simple-cdd.html)